# Can't access Youtube using Chrome : Error

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

While I am trying to access youtube using chrome 22.0.1229.94 m(I am on windows 7), I am getting the following error,

```
<wml><card id="error" title="Error"><p> Service Unavailable, Please try later</p></card></wml>
```

I can access youtube using IE and FF.

My question is purely from a technical standpoint,

What's the meaning of this error? and how can I solve it?

Comment: wml...? do you have some kind of mobile emulator/extension or something else that would make youtube think you're using a mobile phone?

Answer (score 1):

Some chrome extension is probably changing your request so that you're asking for mobile content..

One possibility is that you're running the [user-agent switcher](http://spoofer-extension.appspot.com/). You can check what user agent you're sending with [whatsmyuseragent.com](http://whatsmyuseragent.com/). It should show something like `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4` for regular chrome in windows 7 in 64-bit environment.

You can check which extensions you have from menu -> settings -> extensions.

Comment: whatsmyuseragent result - `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1229.94 Safari/537.4` [Here](http://i39.photobucket.com/albums/e179/iamcreasy/Untitled_zps4cb34f6e.jpg) is a list of plugins that I am using. I tried again and even in Incognito, I am getting the same error.

Comment: um, didn't you just tell in another comment that you don't get the error there?

Comment: Yeh, I tried later and it wasn't working. Deleting my comment to avoid confusion.